# Combining 3 lists into single collection with unique values

Tags: java, list, arraylist, collections, set

I have 3 lists in Java as below

```
List<Integer> list1 = query1MysqlRepository.getprocessIds();
List<Integer> list2 = query2MysqlRepository.getprocessIds();
List<Integer> list3 = query3MysqlRepository.getprocessIds();
```

I want to combine the above three `Integer List` into a single collection such that  the collection doesn't contain any duplicate values

```
Collection = list1 + list2 + list3
```

Please suggest what collection can be used here.

Comment: If you don't want any duplicate values you can use a `Set`

Comment: Can you please suggest how will it look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
List<Integer> result = Stream.of(list1, list2, list3)
        .flatMap(Collection::stream)
        .distinct()
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

**OR** if you want to avoid any future duplicate additions:-

```
Set<Integer> result = Stream.of(list1, list2, list3)
        .flatMap(Collection::stream)
        .collect(Collectors.toSet());
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a [`Set`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Set.html) which does not allow duplicates, and simply use the `addAll()` method to add all the elements of the `List`'s to the `Set`:

```
List<Integer> arr1 = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(1,2,3));
List<Integer> arr2 = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(2,3,4)); 
List<Integer> arr3 = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(4,5,6));
Set<Integer> hashSet = new HashSet<>();
hashSet.addAll(arr1);
hashSet.addAll(arr2);
hashSet.addAll(arr3);
hashSet.forEach(System.out::println);
```

***Output:***

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
```